# Delegate events not called for custom view class in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, delegates, interface-builder

I'm trying to play a youtube video using

[Swift-Youtube-Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player)

and I'm currently having trouble with the delegate methods not being called.

I have created an outlet from IB to this player, but I couldn't drag the delegate to the view controller from IB for some reason so I tried to do it in code.

This is what I tried:

```
@IBOutlet weak var youtubePlayer: YouTubePlayerView!

    var _currentYoutubeId: String = "";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(_currentYoutubeId)
        youtubePlayer.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func playerReady(videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView) {
        print(videoPlayer)
        if youtubePlayer.ready {
            youtubePlayer.playerVars = [
                "playsinline": "1",
                "controls": "0",
                "showinfo": "0"
            ]
            youtubePlayer.loadVideoID(_currentYoutubeId)
            if youtubePlayer.playerState != YouTubePlayerState.Playing {
                youtubePlayer.play()
            } else {
                youtubePlayer.pause()
            }
        }

    }

    func playerStateChanged(videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView, playerState: YouTubePlayerState) {
        print("promjena")
    }

    func playerQualityChanged(videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView, playbackQuality: YouTubePlaybackQuality) {
        print("promjena")
    }
```

I'm doing this in the newest XCode versions and I'm very new to iOS, Swift and everything Apple related.

Concretely, my question is how to connect this delegate to the player so that its lifecycle methods are called?

EDIT: I have previously managed to this with UICollectionViewDelegate, but I haven't succeded with this custom view.

Comment: you did show that you    assign delegates to your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way I use Swift-Youtube-Player.

```
class videoController: UIViewController, YouTubePlayerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView!
var videoID: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    videoPlayer.delegate = self

    if let videoID = self.videoID {
        videoPlayer.loadVideoID(videoID)
    }
}

func playerReady(videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView) {
    videoPlayer.play()
}

func playerStateChanged(videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView, playerState: YouTubePlayerState) {
    if videoPlayer.playerState == YouTubePlayerState.Ended || videoPlayer.playerState == YouTubePlayerState.Paused {
        //Your code here
    } 
}

func playerQualityChanged(videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView, playbackQuality: YouTubePlaybackQuality) {
    //Your code here
}

}
```